# Why is it when I run this procedure it asks me to bind variables?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm writing a procedure so that the full list of stock can be seen but also when the stock level is lower than the minimum stock level it outputs an extra line.. however, when I run the procedure it asks me to bind a variable to the stock_cursor.stock_qty value which I am very confused about as there's already data in the table.. any ideas why this is occurring?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stockLevel AS
BEGIN
FOR stock_cursor IN
( SELECT toy_name, stock_qty, min_stock_qty FROM w_toy_stock) 
   LOOP DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stock_cursor.toy_name ||' '||stock_cursor.stock_qty ||' '|| stock_cursor.min_stock_qty);
   IF :stock_cursor.stock_qty < stock_cursor.min_stock_qty THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Stock is too low');
   END IF;
   END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: As a side observation, I do hope this is just a homework exercise  dbms_output.put_line should not be used in real application code except for debugging during testing.  PL/SQL has no way of directly interacting with the client, and the ouput of dbms_output does _not_ go to your screen.  It goes to a buffer, and it is up to the client process (sqlplus, sql Dev, etc., etc) to then choose to display it, or not.  And then, only on completion of the entire PL/SQL procedure and control returns to the client, allowing it to make that decision.

Comment: Also, in your code, `stock_cursor` is not a cursor but a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have `:stock_cursor` in your code. Remove the `:` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include ":" in your code.
use :

```
IF stock_cursor.stock_qty < stock_cursor.min_stock_qty THEN
```